Whats is a good way to add a column to an existing sql database table using spark?
I have an existing Postgres SQL table with some features.
I want to use spark to :

Read that table
Create some additional columns
Add those columns to the table.

Is there any way to make spark add the column to an existing database, without overriding the entire table, and without using additional libraries?
So far, the only ways I could think of to add the new columns to the database using spark were:

To make spark add the columns to a SQL table by replacing the table with df.write.mode('overwrite'), but that's dangerous and inefficient.
To write a transformer that uses psycopg and inserts the new column to the database, and then include the transformer at the end of the pipeline. It does seem like a better alternative, but it does feel a bit convoluted.


Data Table Context
If using Hive tables, some Spark DDL commands are available but not all. The ADD COLUMN command is one that works with Hive tables. The below example explains the process of adding columns to Hive tables. Some Spark DDL commands do not work with Hive tables (such as REPLACE COLUMN and DROP COLUMN)
If using Spark V2 tables, the data infrastructure set up will require a metadata store (like Apache Iceberg) in order to complete actions like adding columns (without overwriting an entire table using). If this is the case, please update the question to clarify the context of your question.
Explanation of different cases
When using Hive tables, Spark DDL commands enable the addition of new columns (defaulting to null) without using df.write.mode('overwrite').
Case 1
The below example shows how to populate existing rows with null values in the new columns. This will enable appending new rows to the table with values populated in the new columns using df.write.mode('append')
Case 2
For any existing rows of data, if you want to populate those columns with data, you will need to overwrite those rows using df.write.mode('overwrite') reference. (Ideally the table has partitions, which will help limit the number of rows you are overwriting at one time.)
Example
Set-Up
Spark Set-Up
import pyspark
APP_NAME = "SMURPHY SAMPLE APP"
SPARK_CONF = [
    ("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "5"),
    ("spark.executor.memory", "10g"),
    ("spark.executor.cores", "4"),
    ("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "2000"),
]
spark_conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
spark_conf.setAppName(APP_NAME)
spark_conf.setAll(SPARK_CONF)
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)

Table Set-Up
sampleJson = '[{"date":"2023-01-02","metric":234},{"date":"2023-01-01","metric":123}]'
sampleDf = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([sampleJson]))
sampleDf.show(truncate=False)




date
metric




2023-01-02
234


2023-01-01
123



TABLE = 'smurphy.smurphy_sample'
sampleDf.write.saveAsTable(f'{TABLE}')
spark.sql(f"""SELECT * FROM {TABLE}""").show()




date
metric




2023-01-02
234


2023-01-01
123



Initial Table
spark.sql(f"""
select * from {TABLE}
""").show()




date
metric




2023-01-02
234


2023-01-01
123



Add column
spark.sql(f"""
ALTER TABLE {TABLE} ADD COLUMN metric_new int
""")

More about Spark DDL commands here: link
See description of the new column in table
spark.sql(f"""
describe {TABLE}
""").show()




col_name
data_type
comment




date
string
null


metric
bigint
null


metric_new
int
null



Append Data
Set-Up
sampleAppendJson = '[{"date":"2023-01-03","metric":567,"metric_new":123}]'
sampleAppendDf = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([sampleAppendJson]))
sampleAppendDf.show(truncate=False)




date
metric
metric_new




2023-01-03
567
123



Append New Data
sampleAppendDf.write.saveAsTable(f'{TABLE}', mode='append')
spark.sql(f"""SELECT * FROM {TABLE}""").show()




date
metric
metric_new




2023-01-03
567
123


2023-01-02
234
null


2023-01-01
123
null




There is no override mode in pyspark. It's overwrite. Also, you have some extra phrases in your answer like [reference][1] which indicates you didn't possibly write this answer. Please read the gen ai policy. Using plagiarized (without proper references) or Gen AI content is prohibited on StackOverflow.

Is it really possible to use the code you are suggesting? How do you create the {table}?
As far as i know the way to make the table name available to spark is to create a temp view from the load method chain, and altering that table won't be allowed since you can't add columns to a view.
And even if you could add tables to a view, how could you apply the changes without overriding the entire table?
If its indeed possible and not a LLM hallucination, please provide a full code example so we can actually use it :)

Hi @VikasSharma Thanks for the catch on the errors. I wrote this answer using a personal juptyer notebook not any gen ai. I tried to format the link to pyspark write documentation using the term "reference" that is fixed (when the URL is not saved correctly it shows [reference][1] instead of a blue underlined word of "reference"). Also fixed the term "override" to "overwrite". Sorry for rushing through this response. Could you please remove your downvote since this was a personal response that works successfully with my infra set-up. Thank you

@HappilyCoding Added more context and an example of creating a table before adding a column. My solution may be specific to a data infra implementation that writes Hive tables. In my case, data is stored as Parquet files on S3, and is organized to resemble a regular database with the AWS Glue Data Catalog. If you are using an infra set-up that does not align with mine and therefore my solution does not work, please update your question to reflect your additional context. Thank you. Let me know how it goes.

@smurphy Oh okay - it's fine. Thanks for the clarification. Also, I didn't downvote your answer - so we're good.

Sounds good! My apologies for the errors in my answer, and thanks for catching them. I specifically come to SO for non "gen ai" answers, so I understand your concern with my original answer looking suspicious.
